# Ok for garage door chain to sag on one side when door is closed?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door, chain

I noticed today that the chain on my garage door seems to droop a bit on one side when the door is closed. I feel like I would have noticed if it was always like this (new unit, about 1.5 years old).

Is this okay/normal? If not, is there a process to tighten it? Seems like it's been nosier lately!

[image: showing drooping chain]

[image: where i guess chain may be able to be tightened?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's normal because the drive is putting some tension on the other side of the chain and that leaves a bit of slack on this side.

Comment: Agree, the User's Manual will probably tell you to adjust the chain tension with the door open. It should tell you how much sag is optimum when the door is open.

Comment: thanks good to know, wasn't sure if the more important was open or close. I will try to find the manual!